# How to echo environment variables in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
  postgres_backup: {}

services:
  postgres:
    build: ./compose/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup:/backups
    env_file: .env

  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile
    user: django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    command: /gunicorn.sh
    env_file: .env

  nginx:
    build: ./compose/nginx
    depends_on:
      - django

    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"


  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
```

And in my .env file, I have:

```
# PostgreSQL
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpass
POSTGRES_USER=postgresuser
```

How do I test if the environment variables are effectively set?

I've tried tu run on the remote machine:

```
docker run sorbetcitron_django echo $POSTGRES_USER
```

where **sorbetcitron_django** is my django image, but it outputs nothing.

Comment: Because `docker run` runs the docker instance directly, not via docker-compose.

Comment: `docker-compose run postgres env` `docker-compose run django env`

Comment: or, once you have started your docker containers `docker exec -it container-id env`

Comment: see my edit for docker-compose

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd use:

```
docker-compose run postgres env
```

If you pass a $POSTGRES_USER to your cli, it's going to get interpreted by the shell on the host, and if you escape the `$`, you'll need to eval the line to get the shell to parse the `$` inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

The command that is purpose-built for this scenario is the [`docker compose config`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_config/) command.

With your `docker-compose.yml`, and associated `.env` file, the `docker compose config` command outputs the following (truncated for brevity):

```
...
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpass
      POSTGRES_USER: postgresuser
...
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpass
      POSTGRES_USER: postgresuser
...
```

I personally like to run:

```
⪼ docker compose config|less
```